# Is it possible to change /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range for a single program?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I know you can bind to a specific port like this:

```c
fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
```

or just bind to port 0 for a selection from `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range`.

But is there a way to change this for a single program? I ask this because I've narrowed an issue to a third party library where it pulls from `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range` to open a port between hosts, but only certain port ranges are open through my firewall for host-host communication. I can change the `ip_local_port_range`, but then it changes for the system which I don't want. Instead, I'd like to narrow this port range for my single program.

Comment: If you know which range you want to use, write code to try ports in that range.  It's not as efficient as the kernel doing it for you, but it's effective nonetheless.  You could try sequential numbers from start to end, or you could try random numbers in the range of open ports (quite probably a better choice, especially if you make sure you don't attempt the same port number multiple times).

Comment: It's a third party library in this case. The only way I can have it try specific ports by writing code is to patch a bind function into their code that tries ports in my range. That's why I'm wondering if it's possible to change it for a single program

Comment: "only certain port ranges are open through my firewall": why? There is no valid security reason for restricting *outbound* ports, and there are significant costs in trying to write applications that can cope with them. Get rid of this rule. It appeals to netadmins because it is symmetrical with inbound port rules, but it has no actual usefulness.

Comment: @user207421 I'm not the person that made the firewall rule, just one that found an issue with it. My ip_local_range is `32768 60999`, should I see if I can remove/get the firewall rules to match that?

Comment: As I said, get them removed. They are holding up development and serve no useful purpose.

Answer (score 1):

As user20742 mentioned, the simplest solution may be to adjust the firewall.

However, it *is* possible to intercept the `open` function [and, possibly, `read`] and detect that the `open` is for `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range`, and redirect to a file of our choosing (e.g.) `/home/me/fake_port_range`

The easiest way to get the fake file is to just manually create it with the range that *will* get through the firewall. But, more elaborate ways are possible: see below.

To do the intercept, we create a shared library file (e.g.) `fake.so` that has *our* fake version of `open`. Then, we force this on the program with:

```
env LD_PRELOAD=fake.so ./myprogram
```

---

Here is some sample source for the fake library:

```
// fake.c -- fake open intercept

#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static int (*real_open)(const char *pathname,int flags,int mode);

int
open(const char *pathname,int flags,...)
{

    // get the address of libc's real open function
    if (real_open == NULL) {
        real_open = dlsym("open",RTLD_NEXT);
        if (real_open == NULL) {
            perror("dlsym/open");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    // do we want to intercept the filename?
    int fakeit = (strcmp(pathname,
        "/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range") == 0);

    // yes, substitute our "fake" version (use whatever name we wish)
    if (fakeit)
        pathname = "/home/me/fake_port_range";

    // get the "mode" arg
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap,flags);
    int mode = va_arg(ap,int);
    va_end(ap);

    // open the file (for real)
    int fd = real_open(pathname,flags,mode);

    return fd;
}
```

---

Build the library with:

```
cc -shared -o fake.so fake.c -fPIC -O2 -ldl
```

---

Creating the fake file manually (e.g. with a text editor) is the simplest (and recommended) method.

However ...

1. We *could* write a standalone program that opens the `/proc` file but then probes all the ports to get the more limited range, and creates the fake file `/home/me/fake_port_range`.
2. To be really elaborate, we could add this probing to the fake `open` function in the `.so` to create it on the fly (once).
3. As a further sophistication, from our `open`, we could create the file, open it, and then `unlink` it, returning the opened `fd`.
4. Instead of creating a file, we could do the probing in `open`, and put the results in a "secret" character string. We add an intercept for `read` to our library, and have the `read` simulate the data from the string. We'd need an array of structs that control the read action, so this option is probably overkill.

Answer (score 1):

The value in

```
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
```

is the range used by the kernel when selecting ephemeral ports (the ports selected by the kernel to use when the user doesn't specify a port with the `bind()` system call)

That's a pool of ports to use... at some point in time somebody wanted to limit the availability of ports to avoid port exhaustion, but as ports are a shared resource, they are selected by the kernel not by the user (this doesn't mean you cannot bind to a port in that range, only that the kernel will assign you a port from that range when a new port is used, when all are in use, the kernel will start denying ephemeral ports and you will have forcibly to `bind()`)  For this reason, there's only one such range per tcp or udp implementation.  If you run a different virtual environment, then you will have a new, completely disjoint, port space on the new implementation of udp or tcp, and for that you will be able to specify the range to use for ephemeral ports.

It's not clear why should you want to somehow reserve some ports for one process and a different range for others.  IMHO you are heading an instance of the XY problem or you don't understand the use of ephemeral ports.  These are used to avoid collisions (this is to avoid the same port be given to two different processes), not to play with them.